# Casting Custom Object from HttpServletRequest session to other custom object in custom javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

I am retrieving custom object (AuthUserInfo) from session in LoginModule Implementation class. This custom object has been set at filter class application level.  When I try to cast this object to `AuthUserInfo` from custom authentication jar throws `ClassCastException.`

We are using weblogic 10.3.

Kindly let me know how to cast properly?

Answer (score 0):

The [ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) means the object is not an instance of `AuthUserInfo`, it could be wrapper or some 'Unknown' object.

In your custom authentication LoginModule implementation, where you have this `ClassCastException`, add the below  line before casting:

```
System.out.println(object.getClass().getName());
```

And then you will know which exactly object type is it, and then you can cast to this type (or a super type).

Comment: I am setting the session value in filter class which resides at  EAR file whereas i am trying to get this via weblogic container custom authentication LoginModule implementation Class                                                                              httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)ch.getValue("com.bea.contextelement.servlet.HttpServletRequest");  
   
    logger.info("request value inside session----"+httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute("user"));
   AuthUserInfo authUser=(com.astrazeneca.login.authentication.AuthUserInfo)httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute("user");

Comment: I am able to print the object which i set at the session in this following line  
logger.info("request value inside session----"+httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute("user"));
when trying to cast only getting an exception. I want to get all the values from the custom object

Comment: Could you please put the line before casting, and advise what the value is?

Comment: This is the value i am getting in logger                                                 
      request value inside session----com.astrazeneca.login.authentication.AuthUserInfo@1e8954a

Comment: This is the value of `object.toString()`, please print `object.getClass().getName()`

Comment: `logger.info("request type ----"+httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute("user").getClass().getName());`

Comment: getting this as a class name -
 com.astrazeneca.login.authentication.AuthUserInfo

Comment: Can you provide the error message of the `ClassCastException`, and is there a possibility that `AuthUserInfo authUser` evaluates to `AuthUserInfo` in a different package?